# Passing an image from Java to JavaFX WebView

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, webview

I've got an application window using JavaFX.
This window contains a simple WebView to display a HTML document.
Inside the HTML document, there is a script tag, executing a Java function, which returns the pixels as int[].
I'm using the following code to draw the image onto the canvas:

```
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageData = context.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);
var buffer8 = new Uint8ClampedArray(imageData.data.buffer);
var buffer32 = new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer);
buffer32.set(pixels);
context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

This works, however performance is about 0.07 seconds per frame, giving me a total of ~ 15 FPS, using a 640x480 canvas currently. My goal is to get at last 30fps for 1920x1080 (currently 5 FPS), and even higher values. The only solution i come up with is to create/populate the whole buffer at once on the java side, but i have no idea how to manage that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of trying to pass an image to WebView, I suggest you create a Group with the WebView on the bottom and a WritableImage in an ImageView on top (positioned where you want it to overlay the WebView) and use a [PixelWriter](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2436712) or set the pixels of the Image (rather than a writable image, you could also create new images as needed and [set them into the ImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721917/display-rtp-mjpeg) as you wish.)

Comment: Thats the fallback solution actualy. As this would make the goal i try to archive almost impossible: multiple images in layers with html decorated windows around them.